# Windows 10 on Ubuntu KVM run very slow after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: windows-10, kvm-virtualization, docker, qemu

I have Windows 10 pro installed from [this guide](https://getlabsdone.com/install-windows-10-on-ubuntu-kvm/) that run Docker container on Ubuntu KVM.
The performance of Windows on Ubuntu 20.04 was very good, but after the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 it is a disaster.
The performance of Ubuntu 22.04 itself remain the same, only the guest is slow.
I suspect two things.

1. Change in Ubuntu's kernel or something that cause the slow performance.
2. Need for update of Windows drivers or something.

I really do not wish to break the system, and I need advice thanks.

Comment: I am having the same symptoms. I sincerely regret doing the upgrade. My Windows VM is running really poorly and the screen viewing has artifacts all over the place whenever I drag any window. I am considering rolling back.